# Question changed in comments

Tags: support

I'm reviewing triage posts and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011898) came up. The question itself was invalidated by the comments; the user confirmed that they're going to try the new suggested approach. What is the correct way to handle a post like this in triage?

Comment: Regardless of what's being said in the comments, this post should be closed.

Comment: @MarounMaroun For what reason?

Comment: @Servy I might be wrong, but describing the problem at the very high level doesn't sound good for me. I expect to see actual code, at least share your thoughts, what have you tried (not "I've tried many things and none worked").

Comment: @MarounMaroun I see no reason for code to be posted here.  The problem isn't at a syntax level, it's a design level.  Posting code wouldn't add anything of value, or help an answerer provide the correct answer to the problem.  It's somewhat uncommon for a good SO question to not need any code, but this is pretty close to the textbook example of an appropriate question that simply needs no code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't say that the question is invalidated.  This is *exactly* why it's a good idea to add context to a problem when posting a question, rather than *just* asking for a solution to the specific technical approach you think might solve it.  The OP went out of his way to make the question *not* be an XY question, and he got an answer that will actually help him as a result.

This all stems from the fact that the OP described the problem that he was having at a high level, mentioned the approach to solving that problem that he thinks might work, and described the problems that he was having with that attempted solution.  An answer *could* resolve the specific problem with his attempted solution, or it could *disregard his attempted solution entirely* and solve the actual problem described.  The responder choose the latter, and the OP seems better for it.

The question could use a bit of editing help, just for some minor presentation issues (superfluous text, minor grammar, etc.), and I suppose it really should got into a bit more detail about why the solution he provided isn't working for him, but the question is fundamentally fine, and I see no close reason that would apply to it.

Comment: Perfect, makes sense to me. Thank you!